# what is benefit of using gson in socket?

Tags: gson

what is the benefit of transform a string in this cod to Gson and then send it through socket in contrast without Gson?

```
String s ="abc";
DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream();

Gson gson=new Gson();
String json= gson.toJson(s);
dos.writeUtf(json);
```

Comment: So that you can easily create the object back from the JSON string.

Comment: i read if i use toJson() and deserialize with fromJson() every client such as .net client or ... can transfer data with server.is it true if i use this method?

Comment: Yes `XML` and `JSON` are good ways to transfer the data rather than Object and plain string.

Comment: if i write server with java and write client with .net and in both of them i use Gson can client and server send and recive data with this way?